# How to add custom button to notification in react native and handle action without opening application, on receiving data only notification

Tags: react-redux, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have to show notification with custom buttons, right now the buttons are showing but on click of them application is opening. but i don't want to open application rather i have to call an API on click of the button.

These are data only notifications.

Here is my code:

```
import {AppRegistry, Platform} from 'react-native';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
console.disableYellowBox = true;

const bgMessaging = async(messages) => {
    console.log("Message",messages);
    const bgNotification = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel("bgNotification","bgNotification",firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max);
     firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(bgNotification);
     let notification_to_be_displayed = new firebase.notifications.Notification({
       show_in_foreground: true,
       title: 'Hello Application',
       body: 'New Invitation',
       android_channel_id:"bgNotification"
     });
     if (Platform.OS == "android") 
     {
       notification_to_be_displayed
         .android.setPriority(firebase.notifications.Android.Priority.High)
         .android.setChannelId("bgNotification")
         .android.setVibrate(5000);
     }

     const action = new firebase.notifications.Android.Action('test_action', 'ic_launcher', 'Accept');
     notification_to_be_displayed.android.addAction(action);

    firebase.notifications().displayNotification(notification_to_be_displayed);      
    return Promise.resolve();
};

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('RNFirebaseBackgroundMessage',() => bgMessaging );
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

Comment: have you got the answer to your question?

Comment: @RaviKumarGopalakrishnan  fixed it using react-native-push-notification.

Comment: @Kailash, can you give any more information about how you did this? I am currently trying to achieve the same thing

Comment: @Kailash, please write the details how did you achieve this))